# How to Link my Prime Number Detector to my Custom Created Array in Python?

Tags: python, arrays

I have a script that works well, which creates an array of all whole numbers inbetween what was inputed. I also have a function that should check if it is prime or not. The think I am stuck on is linking the prime checker to scan through the array to see if it is prime or not. The end goal for the program is to scan the array, save the prime numbers into a Prime number array, and put all others into a not prime array.

```
# with integers within given range
r1, r2 = 2, 100

# Function which takes aforementioned values, takes first value, adds 1, then repeats until final value is reached.
def createList(r1, r2):
    return list(range(r1, r2 + 1))
# printing the function which created the array
print(createList(r1, r2))
createdList = createList(r1, r2)

# takes array and starts a loop for the whole array to check if it is prime


        def isprime(n):
            if n == 2:
                return "Prime"
            if n == 3:
                return "Prime"
            if n % 2 == 0:
                return "Not Prime"
            if n % 3 == 0:
                return "Not Prime"
            i = 5
            w = 2
            while i * i <= n:
                if n % i == 0:
                    return "Not Prime"
                i += w
                w = 6 - w
            return "Prime"
```

I have built the steps leading up to it, and what is needed to do the calculations, but I can't build the logic that stores it If i can't get values to test it. I completed the first and third step, but I need assistance connecting them to complete the fourth step. Also I know that These are already a thing, but I want to make my own database of prime and non prime numbers for use in this project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you need to complete your logic of finding prime numbers from a list of numbers. If so, you need a loop to test each number in your list of numbers.

The following code uses your `isprime` function, and would create one list to store prime numbers and another list to store non-prime numbers.

```py
# create 2 empty lists
prime_list = []
non_prime_list = []

# use a loop to test each number.
for number in createdList:
    return_value = isprime(number)
    if return_value == "Prime":
        # this number is a prime number, append it to prime_list
        prime_list.append(number)
    else:
        non_prime_list.append(number)

# print the result
print("prime_list =", prime_list)
print("non_prime_list =", non_prime_list)
```